# Direct summands of direct sums of indecomposable modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I would like to know whether the following proposition is true or false:
Given indecomposable modules $G_1, ..., G_n$, let $G = G_1 \oplus \cdot \cdot \cdot \oplus G_n$. If $D$ is a direct summand of $G$ then $D$ is isomorphic to some $H_1 \oplus \cdot \cdot \cdot \oplus H_n$ where $H_j$ is either $0$ or $G_j$.
I know it's true if we say simple instead of indecomposable, but I cannot prove this case or find a counter-example.

Comment: I did mean what you guessed, and now see that your question is not actually so obvious. $\hspace{1.36 in}$ (and that I don't know the answer) $\;\;\;\;$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proposition is false.

Counterexample: take $R=k[x,y]$, where $k$ is a field. Let $I:=(x,y) \subseteq R$ and $J:=(x-1, y) \subseteq R$. Define a surjective map of $R$-modules

$$f: I \oplus J \to R$$

given by addition (here, think of $I \oplus J$ as being an "external" direct sum, since obviously these ideals have non-trivial intersection inside $R$). We have a short exact sequence:

$$0 \to \ker(f) \to I \oplus J \to R \to 0.$$

$R$ is projective, so this sequence splits. Thus, $R$ is a direct summand of $I \oplus J$.

It is not hard to see that $I$ and $J$ are indecomposable. But, neither is principal, so neither is isomorphic to $R$ as an $R$-module, since $R$ is a cyclic $R$-module. Also, clearly $I \oplus J$ is not isomorphic to $R$ as an $R$-module.

Comment: By the way, your proposition holds for modules over rings that have something called the Krull-Remak-Schmidt property (some people call it the Krull-Schmidt property). There are lots of references that have more details on the KRS property, but a good one is "Cohen-Macaulay Representations", by Leuschke and Wiegand.

Comment: Chapter 8 of Carl Faith's *Rings and Things* is dedicated to a neat overview of Krull-Schmidt as well.